# Eclipse "The local variable b is never read" msg although i assign and use the boolean java variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, boolean

When i try following java code
Assign `false` value to my boolean variable `b` and use it on if condition on the same statement
There is a message from eclipse IDE
Which hint me that `"The local variable b is never read"`

```
boolean b = false;
 if (b = false) { // boolean assignment & usage on one statement
    System.out.println("true");
}else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

Kindly show why this message appeared although i use my variable?
Note : if condition is that `b==false` the message will not be shown

Comment: `b = false` is an assignment, and you don't use `b` afterwards: you'd get the same behaviour from `if (false)`. You presumably mean `b == false`, or `!b`.

Comment: You only assign to the variable. You are never reading from it. In the if statement, the validity is not being tested of that variable. The validity is being tested of that assignment statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assign false value to my boolean variable b and use it on if condition

The first part of that is correct: You assign a value to `b`. The second part is not: You never use `b` there. You use the result of the assignment, which is the value `false`, not anything to do with `b`.

This would be assigning *and then using* `b`:

```
b = false;
if (b) {
```

But this:

```
if (b = false)
```

is just an assignment to `b`, and then using the value `false`.

So the error is correct: `b` is assigned a value, and its value is never used.